# Borrow inside a loop

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust after many years of C++. I have a situation where the compiler is complaining about a borrow, and it doesn't seem to matter whether it is mutable or immutable. I don't seem to be able to use `self` as a parameter inside a loop that start with: `for item in self.func.drain(..)`.
I've tried calling `appropriate()` as a function:

```
Self::appropriate(&self,&item,index)
```

and I have tried it as a method:

```
self.appropriate(&item,index)
```

but I get the same message in either case:
The function or method `appropriate()` is intended imply examine the relationship among its parameters and return a `bool` without modifying anything. How can I call either a function or method on `self` without violating borrowing rules?
This program is a learning exercise from `exercism.org` and doesn't include a `main()` so it won't run but should almost compile except for the error in question. Here's the code I have:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub type Value = i32;
pub type Result = std::result::Result<(), Error>;

pub struct Forth {
    v: Vec<Value>,
    f: HashMap<String,usize>,
    s: Vec<Vec<String>>,
    func: Vec<String>
}


#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    DivisionByZero,
    StackUnderflow,
    UnknownWord,
    InvalidWord,
}

impl Forth {
    pub fn new() -> Forth {
        let mut temp: Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new();
        temp.push(Vec::new());
        Forth{v: Vec::<Value>::new(), f: HashMap::new(), s: temp, func: Vec::new()}
    }

    pub fn stack(&self) -> &[Value] {
        &self.v
    }

    pub fn eval(&mut self, input: &str) -> Result {
        self.v.clear();
        self.s[0].clear();

        let mut count = 0;

        {
            let temp: Vec<&str> = input.split(' ').collect();
            let n = temp.len() as i32;
            for x in 0..n as usize {
                self.s[0].push(String::from(temp[x]));
            }
        }

        let mut collecting = false;
        let mut xlist: Vec<(usize,usize)> = Vec::new();
        let mut sx: usize = 0;
        let mut z: i32 = -1;
        let mut x: usize;
        let mut n: usize = self.s[0].len();

        loop {
            count += 1;
            if count > 20 {break;}

            z += 1;
            x = z as usize;
            if x >= n {break;}
            z = x as i32;
            
            let word = &self.s[sx][x];

            if word == ";" {
                if collecting {
                    collecting = false;
                    let index: usize = self.s.len();
                    self.s.push(Vec::<String>::new());
                    for item in self.func.drain(..) {
                        if self.s[index].len() > 0 &&
                            Self::appropriate(&self,&item,index)
                        {
                            let sx = *self.f.get(&self.s[index][0]).unwrap();
                            let n = self.s[sx].len();
                            for x in 1..n as usize {
                                let symbol = self.s[sx][x].clone();
                                self.s[index].push(symbol);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            self.s[index].push(item);
                        }
                    }
                    self.f.insert(self.s[index][0].clone(), index);
                    self.func.clear();
                    continue;
                }
                if 0 < xlist.len() {
                    (x, n) = xlist.pop().unwrap();
                    continue;
                }
                return Err(Error::InvalidWord);
            }
            if collecting {
                self.func.push(String::from(word));
                continue;
            }
            if Self::is_op(word) {
                if self.v.len() < 2 {
                    return Err(Error::StackUnderflow);
                }
                let b = self.v.pop().unwrap();
                let a = self.v.pop().unwrap();
                let c = match word.as_str() {
                    "+" => a + b,
                    "-" => a - b,
                    "*" => a * b,
                    "/" => {if b == 0 {return Err(Error::DivisionByZero);} a / b},
                    _ => 0
                };
                self.v.push(c);
                continue;
            }
            match word.parse::<Value>() {
                Ok(value) => { self.v.push(value); continue;},
                _ => {}
            }
            if word == ":" {
                collecting = true;
                self.func.clear();
                continue;
            }
            if word == "drop" {
                if self.v.len() < 1 {
                    return Err(Error::StackUnderflow);
                }
                self.v.pop();
                continue;
            }
            if word == "dup" {
                if self.v.len() < 1 {
                    return Err(Error::StackUnderflow);
                }
                let temp = self.v[self.v.len() - 1];
                self.v.push(temp);
                continue;
            }
            if !self.f.contains_key(word) {
                return Err(Error::UnknownWord);
            }
            xlist.push((sx,n));
            sx = *self.f.get(word).unwrap();
            n = self.s[sx].len();
            z = 0;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn is_op(input: &str) -> bool {
        match input {"+"|"-"|"*"|"/" => true, _ => false}
    }

    fn appropriate(&self, item:&str, index:usize) -> bool
    {
        false
    }

    fn prev_def_is_short(&self, index: usize) -> bool {
        if index >= self.s.len() {
            false
        }
        else {
            if let Some(&sx) = self.f.get(&self.func[0]) {
                self.s[sx].len() == 2
            }
            else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error message relates to the call to `appropriate()`. I haven't even written the body of that function yet; I'd like to get the parameters right first. The compiler's complaint is:

```
As a subroutine call

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:85:47
   |
81 |                     for item in self.func.drain(..) {
   |                                 -------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 mutable borrow later used here
...
85 |                             Self::appropriate(&self,&item,index)
   |                                               ^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.


as a method call

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:85:29
   |
81 |                     for item in self.func.drain(..) {
   |                                 -------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 mutable borrow later used here
...
85 |                             self.appropriate(&item,index)
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

Is there any canonical way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `self.func.drain()` will consume the elements contained in `self.func`, thus an **exclusive** (`&mut`) access is needed on `self.func` for the entire `for` loop.
If during the iteration you need to pass a reference to `self` globally, then its `func` member is potentially accessible while the loop holds an exclusive access to it: Rust forbids that.

Since you use `drain()` in order to consume all the elements inside `self.func`, I suggest you swap this vector with an empty one just before the loop, then iterate on this other vector that is not anymore part of `self`.
No copy of the content of the vector is involved here; `swap()` only deals with pointers.

Here is an over-simplified version of your code, adapted consequently.

```rust
struct Forth {
    func: Vec<String>,
}

impl Forth {
    fn eval(&mut self) {
        /*
        for item in self.func.drain(..) {
            self.appropriate(&self);
        }
        */
        let mut func = Vec::new();
        std::mem::swap(&mut self.func, &mut func);
        for item in func.drain(..) {
            let b = self.appropriate();
            println!("{:?} {:?}", item, b);
        }
    }

    fn appropriate(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Forth {
        func: vec!["aaa".into(), "bbb".into()],
    };
    f.eval();
}
```

Comment: Oh, good idea with `swap`! No cloning of vectors required, and the semantics are still equivalent to the original. I never think to use that.

Comment: Note that you don't even need to `drain(..)` if you have extracted `func` out of `self`. And also, you can use `std::mem::take()`, which is equivalent to swapping with a default-constructed value: `for item in std::mem::take(&mut self.func) { ... }`

Comment: Even when you don't want the default value, use `std::mem::replace()` and not `std::mem::swap()`.

Comment: What finally fixed this code for me was replacing `drain(..)` with `iter()`. `drain(..)` had worked fine until I added the new function call inside the loop, and then it was no longer appropriate.

Comment: @Logicrat Ah? OK, I didn't take the time to understand your algorithm and was just assuming you really needed the usage of `.drain(..)`. Yes, it's much simpler if `.iter()` is sufficient.